# Jest, testing object contains correct function type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have this method:

```
export function getTableConfig(priceEntity: any) {
  const columns: any = { columns: [] };
  const keys: Array<string> = Object.keys(priceEntity);
  keys.forEach((key: string) => {
    columns.columns.push({
      key: key,
      label: key,
      values: (obj: any) => ({ value: obj[key] })
    });
  });

  return columns;
}
```

I am trying to test the return using Jest. I wrote something like this:

```
expect(tableConfig).toEqual({
  columns: [
    { key: 'id', label: 'id', values: expect.any(Function) },
  ]
});
```

But I'd like to be more specific regarding the type of the function, something like

```
expect(tableConfig).toEqual({
  columns: [
    { key: 'id', label: 'id', values: (obj: any) => ({ value: string }) }
  ]
});
```

But I have no idea how to do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
expect(tableConfig).toEqual({
  columns: [
    { key: 'id', label: 'id', values: (obj: any) => ({ value: string }) }
  ]
});
expect(tableConfig.columns[0].values({id: 'testId'})).toBe('testId');
```